# How do I implement filtering in CRUD table?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend

Frontend code:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Navbar from "../Navbar/Navbar.js";
import BarChart from "../BarChart/BarChart";
import {
  Chart,
  Tooltip,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  Title,
  LineController,
  LineElement,
  PointElement,
} from "chart.js";
import Card from "../Card/Card.js";
import CardHeader from "../Card/CardHeader.js";
import CardIcon from "../Card/CardIcon.js";
import CardBody from "../Card/CardBody";
import CardFooter from "../Card/CardFooter";
import GridItem from "../Grid/GridItem.js";
import GridContainer from "../Grid/GridContainer.js";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Table from "../Table/Table";
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";
import Danger from "../Typography/Danger.js";
import Warning from "@material-ui/icons/Warning";
import DateRange from "@material-ui/icons/DateRange";
import Update from "@material-ui/icons/Update";
import Store from "@material-ui/icons/Store";
import LocalOffer from "@material-ui/icons/LocalOffer";
import Accessibility from "@material-ui/icons/Accessibility";
// import { Icon, InlineIcon } from '@iconify/react';
import contentCopy from "@iconify-icons/mdi/content-copy";
import styles from "../../assets/jss/material-dashboard/views/dashboardStyle.js";

import Map from "../Map/map";

import Axios from "axios"; //axios library to make requests to api
import "./Home.css";
import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate";
import ReactExport from "react-data-export";

const ExcelFile = ReactExport.ExcelFile;
const ExcelSheet = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelSheet;

Chart.register(
  Tooltip,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  Title,
  LineController,
  LineElement,
  PointElement
);

function Home(props) {
  //make an axios request to get intents data from database
  const [intentsList, setintentsList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/intents").then((response) => {
      setintentsList(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const [customerList, setCustomerList] = useState([]); //store all that information of the database in a list
  //make an axios request to get information from database
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/customers").then((response) => {
      setCustomerList(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const updateCustomerContacted = (ID) => {
    Axios.put("http://localhost:3001/update", {
      contacted: newContacted,
      ID: ID,
    }).then((response) => {
      setCustomerList(
        customerList.map((val) => {
          const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleDateString(
            "en-CA"
          );
          const timeStr = new Date(
            val.latest_time_of_visit
          ).toLocaleTimeString();
          const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;

          return val.ID == ID
            ? {
                ID: val.ID,
                name: val.name,
                email: val.email,
                counts_of_visit: val.counts_of_visit,
                latest_time_of_visit: dateTime,
                contacted: newContacted,
              }
            : val;
        })
      );
    });
  };

  //delete function
  const deleteCustomer = (ID) => {
    Axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/stats/delete/${ID}`).then(
      (response) => {
        setCustomerList(
          customerList.filter((val) => {
            return val.ID != ID;
          })
        );
      }
    );
  };

  //pagination
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);
  const customersPerPage = 5; //change this number according to desired number of rows in a page
  const pagesVisited = pageNumber * customersPerPage;
  const displayCustomers = customerList
    .slice(pagesVisited, pagesVisited + customersPerPage)
    .map((val, key) => {
      const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleDateString(
        "en-CA"
      );
      const timeStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleTimeString();
      const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{val.ID}</td>
          <td>{val.name}</td>
          <td>{val.email}</td>
          <td>{val.counts_of_visit}</td>
          <td>{dateTime}</td>
          <td>{val.contacted}</td>
          <td>
            <select
              onChange={(event) => {
                setNewContacted(event.target.value);
              }}
            >
              <option value="" selected disabled hidden>
                Select Yes/No
              </option>
              <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
              <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
            <button
              className="btn btn-primary"
              onClick={() => {
                updateCustomerContacted(val.ID);
              }}
            >
              Update
            </button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button
              className="btn btn-danger"
              onClick={() => {
                deleteCustomer(val.ID);
              }}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  //to account for the fact that total number of customers cannot be divided equally among the pages
  const pageCount = Math.ceil(customerList.length / customersPerPage);
  //page change
  const changePage = ({ selected }) => {
    setPageNumber(selected);
  };

  //update contacted column
  const [newContacted, setNewContacted] = useState(0);

  {
    /*}
      const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(1);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/time")
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => {
            setCurrentTime(data.time);
          });
      }, []);
    */
  }

  //export to csv function

  const DataSet = [
    {
      columns: [
        {
          title: "S/N",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 100 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Customer Information",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Customer Email",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Counts of Visit",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 175 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Latest Time of Visit",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Contacted?",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
      ],
      data: customerList.map((val) => [
        { value: val.ID, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.name, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.email, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.counts_of_visit, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.latest_time_of_visit, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.contacted, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
      ]),
    },
  ];

  const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);
  const classes = useStyles;

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <GridContainer>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
          {" "}
          {/*width for different screen sizes*/}
          <Card>
            <CardHeader color="warning" stats icon>
              <CardIcon color="danger">
                <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Product Statistics</h4>
                {/* <Icon>content_copy</Icon> */}
              </CardIcon>
              <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Used Space</p>
              <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>
                49/50 <small>GB</small>
              </h3>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
              <BarChart />
            </CardBody>
            <CardFooter stats>
              <div className={classes.stats}>
                <Danger>
                  <Warning />
                </Danger>
                <a href="#pablo" onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}></a>
              </div>
            </CardFooter>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
          <Card>
            <CardHeader color="dark" stats icon>
              <CardIcon color="dark">
                {/* <Store /> */}
                <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Locations</h4>
              </CardIcon>

              <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Revenue</p>
              <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>$34,245</h3>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
              <Map />
            </CardBody>
            <CardFooter stats>
              <div className={classes.stats}>
                <DateRange />
              </div>
            </CardFooter>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
        {/* <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
                    <Card>
                        <CardHeader color="danger" stats icon>
                        <CardIcon color="danger">
                            <Icon>info_outline</Icon>
                        </CardIcon>
                        <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Fixed Issues</p>
                        <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>75</h3>
                        </CardHeader>
                        <CardFooter stats>
                        <div className={classes.stats}>
                            <LocalOffer />
                            
                        </div>
                        </CardFooter>
                    </Card>
                    </GridItem>
                    <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
                    <Card>
                        <CardHeader color="info" stats icon>
                        <CardIcon color="info">
                            <Accessibility />
                        </CardIcon>
                        <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Followers</p>
                        <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>+245</h3>
                        </CardHeader>
                        <CardFooter stats>
                        <div className={classes.stats}>
                            <Update />
                           
                        </div>
                        </CardFooter>
                    </Card>
                    </GridItem> */}
      </GridContainer>

      <GridContainer>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
          <Card>
            <CardHeader color="warning">
              <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Customer Information</h4>
              {/*}
              <p className={classes.cardCategoryWhite}>
                Visitors since 16th May, 2021
              </p>
                */}
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
              <div className="dashboardcontainer">
                <div className="container"></div>
                <table className="customertable">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>S/n</th>
                      <th>Customer Name</th>
                      <th>Customer Email</th>
                      <th>Counts of Visit</th>
                      <th>Latest Time of Visit</th>
                      <th>Contacted?</th>
                      <th>Edit Contacted</th>
                      <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>{displayCustomers}</tbody>
                </table>
                <ReactPaginate
                  previousLabel={"Previous"}
                  nextLabel={"Next"}
                  pageCount={pageCount}
                  onPageChange={changePage}
                  containerClassName={"paginationBttns"}
                  pageLinkClassName={"paginationNumber"}
                  previousLinkClassName={"previousBttn"}
                  nextLinkClassName={"nextBttn"}
                  disabledClassName={"paginationDisabled"}
                  activeClassName={"paginationActive"}
                />
                <ExcelFile
                  filename="Customer Information"
                  element={
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="btn btn-success float-right m-3"
                    >
                      Export to CSV
                    </button>
                  }
                >
                  <ExcelSheet
                    dataSet={DataSet}
                    name="Customer Information Report"
                  ></ExcelSheet>
                </ExcelFile>
              </div>
              {/*}
              <Table
                tableHeaderColor="warning"
                tableHead={["ID", "Name", "Salary", "Country"]}
                tableData={[
                  ["1", "Dakota Rice", "$36,738", "Niger"],
                  ["2", "Minerva Hooper", "$23,789", "Curaçao"],
                  ["3", "Sage Rodriguez", "$56,142", "Netherlands"],
                  ["4", "Philip Chaney", "$38,735", "Korea, South"],
                ]}
              />
            */}
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
      </GridContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Backend code:

```
//set up express server
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
//set up sql server
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
//create a variable called db to make your SQL Statements
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  user: "",
  host: "",
  password: "",
  database: "",
});

//GET REQUEST to database to retrieve customers information from database
app.get("/customers", (req, res) => {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM customer_info", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});

//Update customers
app.put("/update", (req, res) => {
  const ID = req.body.ID;
  const contacted = req.body.contacted;

  db.query(
    "UPDATE customer_info SET contacted = ? WHERE ID = ?",
    [contacted, ID],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.send(result);
      }
    }
  );
});

//Delete customers
app.delete("/stats/delete/:ID", (req, res) => {
  const ID = req.params.ID;

  db.query("DELETE FROM customer_info WHERE ID = ?", ID, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});

//api call to pull intents data
app.get("/intents", (req, res) => {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM data_analytics", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});

//check if backend server is running
app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("Your server is running on port 3001");
});
```

Drawing reference to above front end and back end code, how can I change my code such that I have filtering implemented in the table, meaning to say I click on the table headers and it sorts itself, then I click again it sorts itself ,then last click it goes back to normal.

Comment: Sorting is not the same as filtering. Which do you want?

Comment: sorting, so like sorting on specific columns

Comment: You'll probably want to do that in the frontend only, since all the data is already loaded, and it'll be faster. There are many libraries that do this, or tutorials showing you how to implement sortable tables with buttons in the table header.

Comment: how then do you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ORDER BY` clause to sort by specific columns in both directions. [Here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/) is a bit more information.

For example:

```js
app.get("/customers", (req, res) => {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM customer_info ORDER BY <YOUR_COLUMN_NAME_HERE> <ASC | DESC>", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: but that is just for one column, but how about all columns

Comment: You can simply `ORDER BY <COLUMN_1> <ASC | DESC>, <COLUMN_2> <ASC | DESC>, <COLUMN_3> <ASC | DESC>` and so on to add more columns.

Comment: but making an api call to front end how

Comment: What do you mean? Your front end can keep the desired sorting order in state (when clicking on heards) and everytime this happens (`useEffect`) you can make an Axios request and include the sorting in the request body or query parameters?

Comment: Or you could simply look at react-table, a React library that handles all the sorting and filtering on the front-end (given you have the data in the first place).

Comment: Oh so useEffect and I make another axios request in backend to query a sorted data?
Means I have to change my table?